# freeCodeCamp Everything Be True Algorithm, undefined ouput

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am having an issue with the Everything Be True challenge on the Intermediate Algorithm Scripting section of freeCodeCamp. The goal for this challenge is to "Check if the predicate (second argument) is truthy on all elements of a collection (first argument).

The problem that I am encountering is that my code outputs "undefined" for certain inputs, but I cannot see any reason why it is doing this. My code is below...

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  var answer;
      var filtColl = collection.filter(function(val) {
return val.hasOwnProperty(pre);
  });
  if (filtColl.length !== collection.length) {
    answer = false;
  } else {
for (var i = 0; i < filtColl; i++) {
  if (filtColl[1][pre] === 0 || filtColl[i][pre] === null || filtColl[i][pre] === "" || filtColl[i][pre] === undefined || filtColl[i][pre] === NaN) {
    answer = false;
  } else {
    answer = true;
    }
  }
}
return answer;
}
    console.log(truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": 
"Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": 
"Po", "sex": "female"}], "sex"));
    console.log(truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": 
"Dipsy"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": 
"female"}], "sex"));
    console.log(truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male", "age": 0}, 
{"user": "Dipsey", "sex": "male", "age": 3}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": 
"female", "age": 5}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female", "age": 4 }], "age"));
    console.log(truthCheck([{"name": "Pete", "onBoat": true}, {"name": "Repeat", 
"onBoat": true}, {"name": "FastForward", "onBoat": null}], "onBoat"));
```

The 2nd console.log correctly outputs as "false", but the other three output as "undefined." I cannot for the life of me figure out why my code is not working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
function truthCheck(col, pre) {

  return col.every(function(val) {
    return val[pre];
  });

}
```

This is a simple enough way of doing it :) it basically returns true or false based on whether every object contains a property matching the second argument exists.

You could even shorten it to this :)

```
truthCheck = (col, pre) => col.every(val => val[pre]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I will explain why your code is not working, (I commented the places that are wrong)

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
 var answer;
 var filtColl = collection.filter(function(val) {
    return val.hasOwnProperty(pre);
 });
 if (filtColl.length !== collection.length) {
  answer = false;
 } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < filtColl; i++) { // i < filtColl.length
        if (filtColl[1][pre] === 0/*filtColl[i][pre]*/ || filtColl[i][pre] === null || filtColl[i][pre] === "" || filtColl[i][pre] === undefined || filtColl[i][pre] === NaN /* cannot check NaN like this */) {
            answer = false; // if it is one is false, you do not need to check others, just put break here.
        } else {
            answer = true;
        }
    }
 }
 return answer;
}
```

If you need to check if it is NaN, you have to use `isNaN()` function. `if(val === NaN)` is giving output as `undefined`. I also do not the reason for this, need to ask someone. But, in here we cannot use `isNaN()` because, all other type excluding numbers are also NaN, thus if we use `isNaN()`, some test cases are also will fail. Therefore we have to use `if(val.toString() === "NaN")`.

This is the working code using your idea.

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
 var answer;
 var filtColl = collection.filter(function(val) {
    return val.hasOwnProperty(pre);
});


 if (filtColl.length !== collection.length) {
  answer = false;
 } 
 else {
  for (var i = 0; i < filtColl.length; i++) {
    if (filtColl[i][pre] === 0 || filtColl[i][pre] === null || filtColl[i][pre] === "" || filtColl[i][pre] === undefined || filtColl[i][pre].toString() === "NaN") {
        answer = false;
        break;
        } else {
            answer = true;
        }
    }
 }
 return answer;
}
```

The is how I did this challenge:

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
// Is everyone being true?
 let newCollection = collection.filter((obj) => {
    if(Boolean(obj[pre])){
        return obj;
    }
 });
 if(collection.length === newCollection.length){
    return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

`Boolean(0), Boolean(null), Boolean(""), Boolean(undefined), Boolean(NaN)` all are `false`.

This is the simple way to do this challenge:

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
// Is everyone being true?
 return collection.every(obj => obj[pre]);
}
```

Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  return collection.every(obj => check(obj, pre));
}

function check(object, property) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(property) && object[property]) return true;
  else return false;
}

console.log(truthCheck([{
      "user": "Tinky-Winky",
      "sex": "male"
    },
    {
      "user": "Dipsy",
      "sex": "male"
    },
    {
      "user": "Laa-Laa",
      "sex": "female"
    },
    {
      "user": "Po",
      "sex": "female"
    }
  ],
  "sex"));
// should return true.

console.log(truthCheck([{
      "user": "Tinky-Winky",
      "sex": "male"
    },
    {
      "user": "Dipsy"
    },
    {
      "user": "Laa-Laa",
      "sex": "female"
    },
    {
      "user": "Po",
      "sex": "female"
    }
  ],
  "sex"));
// should return false.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {      
    return collection.every(obj=>Boolean(obj[pre]));           
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more context to your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Thanks!